# controlling namespaces while importing modules in python

Tags: python

I have split a project that i write from 1 file to several files
The thing is, that i have around 50 classes that I created and are called from the main file, I don't want to rewrite all those class references and add the module name before each class.

I tried to make all those classes accessible through 1 package (Tokens)

So I have

```
Main.py
Tokens / 
   __init__.py
   Gen.py
   BuilltIns.py
```

The Idea was to populate the package namespace with all the classes, and then import the package inside Main.py

```
__init__.py:
from Gen import *
from BuilltIns import *

Main.py:
from Tokens import *
```

When I ran `__init__` it works perfectly, and `dir()` reveals that all class names are imported to package namepace.

However, when i run `Main.py`, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Tokens import *
  File "..\Tokens\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Gen import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Gen'
```

How should I extract the 60+ classes from Main.py to other modules without rewriting all the calls for those classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `from Tokens.Gen import ...` since `Tokens` is the package where the `Gen` module resides. The import path should be relative to the main script, unless you've modified the `sys.path` to specify additional directories to be searched during imports.

Alternatively, in `Tokens/__init__.py` you can do `from .Gen import *` (note the `.` before `Gen`). This denotes a [relative import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports). What happens when you run the main script is that the current working directory is added to the paths to be searched during imports, so when `from Gen import ...` is encountered only the default locations are searched (which doesn't include the `Tokens` directory). By using a relative import you tell Python where it can find that module *relative* to the current one.

Note that you can define your classes in [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64130/3767239) in order to constrain what will be imported during `from ... import *`. This way you don't leak other names in your main script's namespace.

Comment: thank you, indeed i had to use explicit relative import